# how to detect if JavaScript whole number is closer to another whole number?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, I may have a random number generated, that may be 3,123, or 3,001, or 2790, etc.. Which JavaScript method will help me out in returning a **target whole integer** because these values...

3,123, or 3,001, or 2790 are closer to 3000, rather than 4000 or 2000, or 1000.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Your question is not clear, do you want to get the closest thousand of a number, the closest to a given target, the different distances towards a target, or something else?

Comment: I fixed up my question for you Mahn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var rand_num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
Math.round((rand_num) / 1000) * 1000;
```

If `rand_num` is 3123, 3001 or 2790, it will be reduced to either 3.123, 3.001 and 2.729 respectively, rounded to 3.0 and multiplied to become 3000.

Comment: I tweaked it up a bit, but this has put me on the road to success! thank you very much Hope!

Comment: This is what I used..  var floor_score = Math.floor(game.score);
    var rounded_score = Math.round((floor_score) / 10000) * 10000;  Thanks again

Answer (score 5):

You could sort them:

```
var numbers = [3123, 3001, 2790, 4000, 2000, 1000];
var target = 3000;
var closest = numbers.sort(function(a, b) {
  var a = Math.abs(a - target);
  var b = Math.abs(b - target);

  return a < b ? -1 : (a > b ? 1 : 0);
});
```

`closest` contains the numbers sorted by their distance from `3000`.

Or you could use a long one-liner:

```
var sorted = numbers.map(function(value, index) {
  return [Math.abs(value - 3000), index];
}).sort().map(function(value, index) {
  return numbers[value[1]];
});
```

Comment: You can't rely on the default sorting function to sort numbers. It sorts based on the stringified value. And I'm not sure why the first `.map` is returning an Array. The sort will be operating on values that look like `"123,0", "1,1", "210,2", etc...`

Comment: How do you suggest I change the code? In Python, I could just do `sorted(numbers, key=lambda n: abs(n - 3000))`, but JS doesn't seem to have something like this.

Comment: I think your first example is suitable. Just your second one doesn't quite work out. No matter what you'll need to pass a function to `.sort()` in order to avoid the `toString` evaluation.